# Remove Wordpress Native Audio Player Skin

Tags: wordpress, audio-player, elementor

Using Wordpress, and the Elementor page builder, I have embedded some audio files to one of my webpages.

However, when we I add the audio player it appears as follows:
[image]

Which is correct - also when loading the page, it initially loads like this.

However, shortly after, the standard Wordpress skin is applied over the one above, and appears as such:

[image]

Hence, my question is: How to stop the Wordpress skin from being applied?
- Is there a setting?
- Or can I comment out the css for their skin?

Any suggestions are welcome, and thank you in advance.

Comment: If you check in firebug with inspect you will find which css is creating the issue

Comment: Is it what you are looking for? Check the 3rd answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875654/how-do-i-style-the-default-wordpress-audio-player-with-css